# Which framework/server should I use (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, mongrel, unicorn

I am making a web app that will process large files (1gb+). While the files are being uploaded, I need to be able to access the file data (whatever is uploaded so far), and also possibly change the location of these uploaded files (currently with mongrel they are in TMP folder).

I know I shouldn't be using RoR to do this as it's too high level. I would need to work with the server like Mongrel or Unicorn, or maybe Rack which as i learned is like a glue between web server and framework like RoR.

My question is,

1. What server/framework (Mongrel, Unicorn, Thin, etc) should I use?
2. Any documentation/guide that will point me to right direction to make this web app
3. Do you recommend doing this with Ruby? I.E, should this be done at a much lower level (like Nginx plugin), or using a Ruby server which stops on top of Nginx is fine?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should use build that server on top of [EventMachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine).

Comment: Hm....thanks for the input. Checking it out.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/).  It's in Ruby and will be easy to pick up if you've been programming with rails, but it doesn't have all the bloat of rails so you can pick and choose what you want to add into it.  You can pick which webserver you want to run it with as well.  I would recommend `Unicorn` as it has multiple threads at once but is much more efficient than mongrel.  [This post describes the benefits of Unicorn well](https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely recommend looking at [EventMachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine).

On top of that, I'd use the [em-http-request](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request) library for streaming file uploads (think of it as async Net::HTTP)

You might find [this talk](http://speakerdeck.com/u/andrew/p/em-vs-node) from Ruby Manor comparing Goliath, Node.js and EM useful as well.